# android test web service in junit and mockito without instrumentation test

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-instrumentation

I have this instrumented test which works fine:

```
@Test
    public void testWebService() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        AuthService authService = new AuthService();
        try {
            AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = authService.authenticate("xx@xxx.com", "xxxx", "xxxxxxx");
            assertNotNull(authenticateResult.getAuthenticationToken());
            assertNotEquals(authenticateResult.getAuthenticationToken(),"");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

        assertEquals("com.roscasend.android.testa", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
```

But I cant figure out how to test the same web service using mockito with junit, in background, without instrumentation test:

```
@Test
    public void testWeb(){
        AuthService mockCalculator = Mockito.spy(AuthService.class);
        EncryptionProvider encryptionProvider = Mockito.spy(EncryptionProvider.class);
        try {
            Mockito.when(mockCalculator.authenticate("xx@xxx.com", "xxxx", "xxxxxxx",
                    encryptionProvider)).thenReturn(authenticateResult);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

// this is the authenticate method from AuthServer class which is called above 

    public AuthenticateResult authenticate(String mUser, String mPassword, String imei,
                                               EncryptionProvider encryptionProvider) throws Exception {
            String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/xxxserver/" + "restXXX" + AUTHENTICATE;
            //Log.d(TAG, "Authenticating user: " + url);
    //      headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

            jsonBody.put("userName", mUser);

            String key = encryptionProvider.buildValidKey(imei);
            if (!mPassword.isEmpty()) {
                mPassword = encryptionProvider.encrypt(mPassword, key);
            }

            jsonBody.put("password", mPassword);
            jsonBody.put("deviceUniqueID", key);


            IHttpRequest postRequest = new PostRequest(url, jsonBody);
            try {
                Reader in = postRequest.sendRequest(); // is throwing an null pointer exception here

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                if (in != null) {
                    AuthenticateRestBean authenticateRestBean = gson.fromJson(in, AuthenticateRestBean.class);
                    if (authenticateRestBean != null) {
                        return authenticateRestBean.getAuthenticateResult();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                InputStream inputStream = postRequest.getErrorStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    String errorStream = AppUtil.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    throw new Exception(errorStream);
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
```

I cant figure out why the code is failing here when is running from background junit test folder and it works when is run from the instrumentation test folder

Reader in = postRequest.sendRequest(); // is throwing an null pointer exception here

[image]

```
import android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Locale;

import ro.star.logger.Logger;
import ro.star.sca.business.util.AppConstants;

public class PostRequest implements IHttpRequest {

private static final String TAG = PostRequest.class.getName();

private final String url;
private final JSONObject jsonObject;
private SimpleArrayMap<String, String> headers;

public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER = "AuthTokenHeader";
public static final String AUTH_GUID_HEADER = "MachineGuidHeader";

private InputStream errorStream;

public PostRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    this.url = url;
    this.jsonObject = jsonObject;

    headers = new SimpleArrayMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    headers.put(PostRequest.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER, AppConstants.TOKEN);
    headers.put(PostRequest.AUTH_GUID_HEADER, AppConstants.GUID);
}

public Reader sendRequest() throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setConnectTimeout(AppConstants.TIMEOUT);
    con.setReadTimeout(AppConstants.TIMEOUT);

    if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=0; i< headers.size(); i++) {
            String key = headers.keyAt(i);
            String value = headers.get(key);
            con.setRequestProperty(key, value);
        }
    }

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    Logger.i(TAG, "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    Logger.i(TAG, "Post parameters : " + jsonObject.toString());
    Logger.i(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

    errorStream = con.getErrorStream();
    return new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
}

@Deprecated
public InputStream sendRequestIS() throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setConnectTimeout(AppConstants.TIMEOUT);
    con.setReadTimeout(AppConstants.TIMEOUT);

    if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=0; i< headers.size(); i++) {
            String key = headers.keyAt(i);
            String value = headers.get(key);
            con.setRequestProperty(key, value);
        }
    }

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    Logger.i(TAG, "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    Logger.i(TAG, "Post parameters : " + jsonObject.toString());
    Logger.i(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

    return con.getInputStream();
}

public InputStream getErrorStream() {
    return errorStream;
}
```

}

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: What is the NPE and what is happening in PostRequest.sendRequest();

Comment: i added the Post Request class

Comment: Try to replace Mockito.spy() with Mockito.mock(). And mock all the things needed to be mocked, also this "PostRequest" also try to mock and return mocked InputStream for it with some mocked json objects. If you need an example how to do it, just let me know.

Trying to make requests out of Unit tests, is very hard and it will take you a lot of effort.

Comment: The main difference between "androidTest" and "test" is in Android framework dependencies. And it possibly be the root cause of your issue. Since there is no details or a full stack-trace of the "null pointer exception", the reason can't be           
 deduced directly.